# How can install Cuda GeForce GT 555m drivers on Ubuntu 12.04 VirtualBox guest?

Tags: installation, nvidia, cuda

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in a Virtual Box as guest OS.  Today I have tried to enable all functions of my graphic card under Ubuntu. But all my efforts were off the mark... because my experience with Linux is relatively small...

I have tried the procedure which is described as in
http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/. Running the cuda-filepack always lead to an error like "installing driver canceled".

Then I have tried to install the Bumblebee project. But I always get the error that the bumblebee daemon is not started. After some internet research I found a test-command:

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]'
```

which results in:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek ... [80ee:beef]
```

I've been trying to activate the card you for hours without success.

Could you please give me some hints how to activate CUDA?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do may not be possible with a standard version of VirtualBox. The issue would be that VirtualBox does not virtualize the GPU. There's hope though. Search the web for `VirtualBox PCI passthrough`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu virtually as a guest, Ubuntu will see a virtual graphics card, specific to VirtualBox. You should not need to install nVidia graphics drivers.

Why are you trying to install a graphics driver in a VirtualBox guest?